# Insufficient funds for gas * price + value in Ropsten

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, tokens, gas-estimate

I write API for smart contract but its shown error "Insufficient funds for gas * price + value"?

My try
I have increased my address balance but it's showing the same error.
I have changed my chain code id but it's showing same error.
I have changed gas price - `tx.gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(1000000);` but its showing same error. I have change provider as ropsten infura but its showing the same error.

My code:

```
async function sendSignedTransactionsForContracts(data, senderAddress, senderPrivateKey) {
    let txObject = {};
    let nonce = null;
    let gasPrice = null;
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await Promise.all([web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress), web3.eth.getGasPrice()])
            .then(result => {
                nonce = result[0];
                gasPrice = result[1];
                gasPrice = (parseInt(gasPrice) + parseInt(gasPrice / 2)).toString();
console.log(gasPrice);
                txObject = {
                    from: senderAddress,
                    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
                    data: data
                };
                return web3.eth.estimateGas(txObject);
            })
            .then(estimateGas => {
                txObject.gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice);
                txObject.gas = web3.utils.toHex(estimateGas);
                const tx = new Tx.Transaction(txObject, {'chain':'ropsten'});
                const privateKey = Buffer.from(senderPrivateKey, 'hex');
                tx.sign(privateKey);
                const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
                const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, async (err, txHash) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                        return
                    }
                    console.log('err:', err, 'txHash:', txHash)
                    let getTransaction = setInterval(async () => {
                        web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, async function (error, result) {
                            if (error) {
                                clearInterval(getTransaction)
                                console.log({ 'errrr': error })
                                reject(error)
                            }

                            if (result) {
                                clearInterval(getTransaction)
                                resolve(result.contractAddress)
                            }
                        });
                    }, 600)
                })
            })
    })
}


async function sendSignedTransactionsForMethods(data, contract_address, senderAddress, senderPrivateKey) {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddress), web3.eth.getGasPrice()])
            .then(async result => {
                nonce = result[0];
                const tx = {
                    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),

                    from: senderAddress,
                    to: contract_address,
                    gas: result[1],
                    data: data,
                    chainId : 3,
                    chain: 'ropsten',
                    hardfork: 'petersburg'
                };

        let gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas(tx);
        tx.gasPrice = web3.utils.toHex(result[1]);
        tx.gas = web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit);

                web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, senderPrivateKey).then(signed => {
                    const tran = web3.eth
                        .sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction, async (err, txHash) => {
                console.log(err);
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err)
                                return
                            }
                            console.log('err:', err, 'txHash:', txHash)
                            // Use this txHash to find the contract on Etherscan!
                             let getTransaction = setInterval(async () => {
                                 await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, async function (error, result) {
                                     if (error) {
                                         clearInterval(getTransaction)
                                         console.log({ 'errrr': error })
                                         reject(new Error(error))
                                     }
                                     resolve(txHash)

                                 });
                             }, 600)

                        });
                });
            })
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the account have enough ether to pay transaction's fees? Is the private key in the right format?

Comment: Yes, Account has enough transaction fees, private key also right format but it has shown this error